# How to find back my lost files

Tags: applications

I lost my photos which was  saved in gallery vault and I can't find it back.i have already tried to recover those in vault settings but  couldn't bargain back and it was found in help icon to contact with gallery vault @thinkyeah.com

Comment: So did you email them? What did they say?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely they're encrypted by Gallery Vault so they're unrecoverable without decryption.

---

You could try to recover the photos from before being placed in Gallery Vault with [DiskDigger on the PlayStore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.defianttech.diskdigger)    This doesn't require root access if the device is running Android 5.0 or above, For some reason all the photos are stored in sort of hidden recycling bin.

> Tip for DiskDigger :
>           If you can't find your photos, try to swap your default storage device in settings > storage to swap the default from internal storage over to SD Card, This sometimes gives DiskDigger the permissions needed to scan the SD Card also, It's because the device actually uses the SD Card as Internal Storage on some devices. The internal storage has read write permissions for DiskDigger to scan it correctly, However the SD Card hasn't got this permission, So it's a good little trick to make it scan the SD Card if you couldn't find the files on Internal Storage